# Unable to change the active pagination button as it refreshes using php

Tags: javascript, php, css, pagination

I am trying to change the active pagination button when I click on it but it refreshes and remains the same as I get data after refresh. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
    ?>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="view_videos.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>               
    <?php  
    }
?>
```

I will be getting urls as:

```
domain.com/hello.php?page=1
domain.com/hello.php?page=2
```

When I click on the second button the url changes to   domain.com/hello.php?page=2 then I want change the background of second button color as active but due to page refresh its not becoming active.

Here is a screenshot of my navigation bar

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Welcome on Stack Overflow ! You have to share a little more of your code if you want us to help you

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the display near the page links? It would be easier if I could picture what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Xatyrian I have changed the background color but it refreshes as when I click on second button in pagination it refreshes so active state is gone I want to know that

Comment: @Xatyrian here is screenshot http://i.imgur.com/TBPExeH.jpg

Comment: Thanks. Now what exactly are you trying to achieve? And can you please be more specific about your issue? Eg explain what you expect to get, and describe what you&#39;re actually getting. Note, you can edit your question to include these things

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon modified question please check it

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks for clearing that up. I'll take a look at it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple:

Get the `page_id` like this:

```
$page_id = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
```

Now you have the number of the current page you are on

Then inside the loop, you could do another check like this:

```
<li class="page-item<?php echo ($page_id == $page) ? ' my-background' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href="view_videos.php?page=<?php echo $page;?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
```

Then you could do this in your `.css-file`:

```
.my-background {
    background-color: #FF0000; /* Maybe add "!important" if necessary */
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap has a `.active` class that is directly usable with his component

Comment: I'm not questioning the bootstrap effectiveness, just showing how it could be done with php.

Comment: I know, but he uses Bootstrap so I can directly use this class instead of your custom class :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the page number from the URL after the page loads, and check it against each page indicator to see if it is the active one. Then you can add a class `active`, and style that in your CSS.

So you can try this:

```
<?php
    for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) { 
        if ($page === $_GET["page"]) {
            $active = " active";
        } else {
            $active = "";
        }
    ?>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link <?= $active ?>" href="view_videos.php?page=<?= $page ?>"><?= $page ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Note: `<?= $foo ?>` is the same as `<?php echo $foo ?>` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)